# Laravel Spatie MultiTenanct noCurrentTenant Exception Handle

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm making a multitenancy system and I'm facing problem when trying to handle the NoCurrentTenant Exception..

I'm using spatie multitenancy

I'm expecting that when there is NoCurrentTenant exception is thrown , it should redirect to login route. But that is not happening.

Below is my Exception Hander register method.

```
public function register() { 
         $this->reportable(function (NoCurrentTenant $e) { 
              return redirect('/saml2/laraveltestidp/login'); 
         }); 
}
```

But even after multiple tries it still shows below error only

```
Spatie\Multitenancy\Exceptions\NoCurrentTenant
The request expected a current tenant but none was set.
```